# Java Socket Issue

Tags: sockets

I'm gonna use Socket() constructor to create a dummy like socket.

what is the difference of using bind() and connect() to this created socket?

if i'm gonna use bind() how can i establish connection or does it directly establish connection?

Answer (score 1):

With a socket you build a connection between two endpoints. One of these endpoints (the *local* one) is on your machine, the other endpoint (the *remote* one) may be anywhere.

With `bind` you set the address of the local endpoint. Often you don't need to do that, since your operating system will take care of the details.

With `connect` you set the address of the remote endpoint and start a connection.